# How to move show entries column to below of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i am trying to do the load on demand by using datatables on my mvc page

if you see in the picture, the show entries is on the top of the datatables

[image]

can i move the show 10 entries to the below of the showing 1 to 10 entries there?.

the following is my html code

```
        <div class="dataTables_hideonload m-b-10">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-vertical-middle table-layout-fixed table-noajax" id="tableCategoryList" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Category ID</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Category Name</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Sort order</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you try to use 
$('#example').DataTable( {"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">' } );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `re-position` it by using:

```
"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
```

[Re-positioning reference](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)